# Searching for specific words in text file Python

Tags: python, search, text-files

I have been creating a program for cataloging and finding books that I have from python to a text file. First, it gives you a list of all the books (which I will sort into alphabetical order at a later date) and then it asks if you would like to add any books and subsequently adds the title and author to the text file. My problem, however, is that afterward I am meant to have the choice to search for a book or author and then you enter either the book name or author and it should search the text file and print out every line with the keywords that have been input into it.

I have looked on multiple forums and tutorials to find out how to do this but none of them seemed to have worked.

My code so far:

```
import time
import random

x = 2

file = open("bookList.txt", "r")
print(file.read())
file.close()

addBookYorN = input("Do you want to add a book to the list? \n")

if addBookYorN in ["Y", "y", "Yes", "yes"]:

while x > 1:
    addBookName = input("Book: ")
    addBookAuthor = input("Author: ")

    file = open("bookList.txt", "a")
    file.write(addBookName + " - ")
    file.write(addBookAuthor + "\n")
    file.close()

    stahp = input("Do you want to add another book? \n")

    if stahp in ["No", "no", "N", "n"]:
        x = x - 1

elif addBookYorN in ["N", "n", "No", "no"]:
    print("Okay")

bookSearchYorN = input("Do you want to find a book or author? \n")

if bookSearchYorN in ["Y", "y", "Yes", "yes"]:
    file = open("bookList.txt", "r")
    bookSearch = input("What book or author are you looking for? \n")
```

Comment: How about trying to read the contents of the file bookList.txt into a python object?  Maybe as a list or a dictionary.  Then you would be able to search the list/dictionary for the title/author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print out every line with the search input you can do.

```
bookSearch = input("What book or author are you looking for? \n")
with open("bookList.txt", r) as infile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        if bookSearch in line:
            print(line)
```

And when you write to the file:

**Replace:**

```
file = open("bookList.txt", "a")
file.write(addBookName + " - ")
file.write(addBookAuthor + "\n")
file.close()
```

**with**

```
with open("bookList.txt", "a") as infile:
    infile.write(addBookName + " - " + addBookAuthor + "\n")
```

This can help return all books written by a specific author.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked perfectly and does exactly what I wanted!